# Junit in android for JSON data

Tags: java, android, json, junit

I would like to add Junit test for `if else` statement using `assertEquals` in android.

My JSON Data

```
"Main": {
            "country": "USA",
            "State": "California",
            "City": "San Jose"
            "Temp" "-10"
               },

 {
            "country": "USA",
            "State": "Texas",
            "City": "Austin"
            "Temp" "10"
               },
 {
            "country": "USA",
            "State": "California",
            "City": "Cupertino"
            "Temp" "00"
               },
```

I am displaying this data base on conditions as below:

```
if (getTemp!=null && getTemp().getFormatted().startWith("-")) {
    displayNegetive.getTemp();
}
else if (getTemp!=null && getTemp().getFormatted().contentEquals("00")) {
    displayZero.getTemp();
}
else {
    displayPositive.getTemp();
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear can you explain it properly.

Comment: I want to add Unittest for below if else statement for the value I am passing in it using assertEquals(Object expected, Object actual) method.